# Can I use an apex 1 crankset with a shimano mtb casette?

Tags: mountain-bike, crankset, compatibility, 1x11

I'm building a mullet 1x11 gravel bike with ultegra shifters, slx rear derailleur and 11 speed 11-46t cassette and am now looking for a oneby crankset. The bike will be used in pretty flat terrain therefore I'm aiming for a 42t crankset.

Can I mix the apex 1 crankset with shimano mtb components?

---

Edit: I will use not the Goatlink 11 but the Tanpan to negotiate between rd and sti.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 1x11 yes, no problem as long as the chainline is a match, which is basically to say as long as the bike is 135mm QR or 142x12.

What doesn't work is the SLX derailleur paired with STI. You need a pull adapter for that. The clean way of doing what you propose at the moment is the Goatlink 11 on RD-RX812 setup, although hopefully that will one day be invalidated by Shimano deciding to make the drivetrains everyone wants to run.

Comment: Forgot to mention that i will use not the Goatlink 11 but the Tanpan to negotiate between rd and sti.